# Facing a problem where the onSaved funtion does not save the incoming data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch the data that's coming from the user (password, email). I made two methods, and connected them to the firebase however I get the password data and the onSaved function for the email is not working it does not pass the email data. tho the structure of the code for the password and the email methods is the same.

`method for the email`

```
 TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue!,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          print("hellllllooooo");
          print(email);
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`method for the working password`

```
TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
return TextFormField(
  obscureText: true,
  onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue!,
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty) {
      removeError(error: kPassNullError);
    } else if (value.length >= 8) {
      removeError(error: kShortPassError);
    }
    password = value;
    return null;
  },
  validator: (value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty && !errors.contains(kPassNullError)) {
      setState(() {
        errors.add(kPassNullError);
      });
      return "";
    } else if (value.length < 8 && !errors.contains(kShortPassError)) {
      setState(() {
        errors.add(kShortPassError);
      });
      return "";
    }
    return null;
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "password",
    hintText: "Enter your password",
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onSaved() function won't be called automatically after successful validation. We have to call `_formKey.currentState.save()` manually to save our variables.
Problem already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908453/flutter-textformfield-onsave-doesnt-get-called-after-successful-validation)

Comment: but how does the password data gets saved?

Comment: @AhmedAl-Khateeb It is saved in your variable `password`.