# How i fix username password email is null in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield

I use widget StatefulWidget and _inputFiled

I've created a model class

```
class Profile {
  String? email;
  String? username;
  String? password;

  Profile({
    this.email,
    this.username,
    this.password,
  });
}
```

And using like

```dart
class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Profile profile = Profile();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
             // _header(context),
              _inputField(context),
             // _forgotPassword(context),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 _inputField(context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          onSaved: (String? email) {
            formKey.currentState?.save();
            profile.email = email!;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        TextFormField(
          onSaved: (String? username) {
            formKey.currentState?.save();
            profile.username = username!;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        TextFormField(
          onSaved: (String? password) {
            profile.password = password!;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            formKey.currentState?.save(); // Save the entire form
            print(
                "email =${profile.email} username =${profile.username} password =${profile.password}");
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) {
              return LoginScreen();
            })));
          },
          child: Text(
            "Register",
          ), 
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

> Terminal say : email =null username =null password =null

Comment: Can you include full sample widget that will produce the error.  The `profile` declaration and use cases are needed to check the error

Comment: Can you show the inputField code?

Comment: _inputField(context) {
return Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
children: [
TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: "Email",
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
borderSide: BorderSide.none),
fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
filled: true,
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
onSaved: (String? email) {
formKey.currentState?.save();
profile.email = email!;
},

Comment: In my git https://github.com/devjinx/appshopping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908453/flutter-textformfield-onsave-doesnt-get-called-after-successful-validation

Answer (score 0):

The form key hasn't been used.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey, // add here
      child: Scaffold(
```

Comment: And must remove `formKey.currentState?.save();` from `onSaved` of TextFIleds

Answer (score 0):

You need put your Global key in your form:

```
  return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Scaffold(
```

And the formKey.currentState?.save() only on

```
 ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            formKey.currentState?.save(); // Save the entire form
            print(
                "email =${profile.email} username =${profile.username} password =${profile.password}");
```

it is not needed in onSave methods as it will be executed first on button onPressed

Answer (score 0):

It is becauae you made them null able and if you dont initialize them the first value will be null.

Comment: Instead of providing the answer directly, try writing a comment explaining the solution if it's not too lengthy. @Erfan Karimi